How can I troubleshoot an authentication issue?
When making a request to http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/reset_password/. The endpoint works only if i include ""rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication" at(DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES) but not when using my Custom authentication "passportBackend.custom_auth.JWTOrOAuth2Authentication".I think the documentation of rest_framework_simplejwt  it returns None when permission is not required.
from rest_framework.authentication import BaseAuthentication
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework import OAuth2Authentication
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed


class JWTOrOAuth2Authentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        
        # Try  authentication
        additional_info = request.META.get("HTTP_X_ADDITIONAL_INFO")
       
        #
        # DRF OAuth2
        #
        
        print(additional_info)
        if additional_info == "OAuth2":
            oauth2_authentication = OAuth2Authentication()
            oauth2_user, oauth2_auth = oauth2_authentication.authenticate(request)
            if oauth2_user is not None:
                return oauth2_user, oauth2_auth
        
        #
        # Simple JWT
        #
        elif additional_info == "jwt":

            jwt_authentication = JWTAuthentication()
            jwt_user, jwt_token = jwt_authentication.authenticate(request)

            if jwt_user is not None:
                return jwt_user, jwt_token
        return None
      

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        # Override this method if needed
        pass

"DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "passportBackend.custom_auth.JWTOrOAuth2Authentication",
        
    ),

How can I troubleshoot an authentication issue with my custom JWTOrOAuth2Authentication class ?
